# Umbraco 5 Custom hive/tree provider - How is the location determined?

Tags: umbraco, provider, umbraco5, umbraco-hive

I'm working with Umbraco 5.1 to implement [this blogpost](http://web-matters.blogspot.com/2011/11/umbraco-5-hive-provider-tree-editor.html) which describes how to create a custom hive provider with a custom tree provider to show data in the content tree. It all works nice, however the nodes show up as follows:

> - Content
>
>   - Music Catalog (the custom one)
>   - Content (default Content node)

[image: Umbraco Tree Output]

So just out of nothing a new *level* of `Content` appears.

Why is this? Is there any way to get the `Music Catalog` node as **a sibling** of `Custom test block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible this, [thread](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/31614-How-do-I-create-subnodes-in-my-tree-controller)  will help you